# Cannot send iCal.net with an image Attachment via MailKit

Tags: icalendar, mailkit

I'm trying to send a .ics file which has been generated via iCal.net. Opening the file in Outlook is fine and has the image attachment I'm trying to send via MailKit, but when sending via Mailkit, the image is not there.

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTACH;FMTTYPE=image/png;X-FILENAME=qrcode.png;VALUE=BINARY;ENCODING=BASE6
 4:iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABkAAAAZAAQMAAAAbwhzkAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAF
 zUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAGUExURQAAAP7+/soH9D0AAAYwSURBVHja7dyxcYNAEAVQPA4UugRKoTRc
 GqW4BIcKNMKBcABzXu8JhIXn/UwSJ/Zt/Oea8Z+kAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBA
 QEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ
 EBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQE
 BAQEBAXkiyGdTn77iaHt79nLHa1oQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ
 EBAQEBAQEBAQEJA9IC+ZVvolhHS3b88hpE+130FAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ
 EBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQP4AMmQK7vNpruVme80OppxAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQE
 BAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQECOCeluH1PdeBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBA
 QEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQkGND4pvaQUBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBA
 QEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBADgYJE0OG+TTh0TggICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgI
 CAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICB7QqqSgpS78TUBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ
 EBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQF5LGRF4h2MjwoICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
 ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICMhGkPI0izvTP6Ju/IosLnk/b1/yBwEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
 AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB+RVyz1+mdjDlEu6gW4wKAgICAgICAgICAgICA
 gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgKyB6Scc1hp76MdjCGk3I0f5jsAAQEBAQ
 EBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQHZBRJ348PhYkhNrb6rWTI
 ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICMi2kB8yPfTRJFKe
 pnz07fbjdX40tT4QEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQE
 JCtICuSqtWndjDllHotCAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA
 gICAjIRpDPpj797B+umSOv08PvGcj0sQUBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQE
 BAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAdkD8pJppV/mkMXRYT5VuRtf3kFXU8kHAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
 AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQF5DGQoltbbImQxzYpMkMVN7SAgICAgICAgICAgI
 CAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAeDnMZEype8p46CgICAgICAgICAgI
 CAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIA8AeSem9pr0oKAgICAgICAgICAgIC
 AgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgOwJSU0zh3ynW7yvOM17ceRurAgICAgI
 CAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICMi2kKr00dFTZgdTrjU7A
 AEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB2RhyvICAgICAgI
 CAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIC
 AgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA
 gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICArMkXJlylJdANIpEAAAAASUVORK5CYILyxAyAPDEDI
 E/MAMgTMwDyxAyAPDEDIE/MAMgTMwDyxAyAPDEDIE/MAMgTMwDyxAyAvDnnbM/wVjPz8rNbZ/
 VpM98ofs/F97vFWfF33MwAyBMzAPLEDIA8MQMgT8wAyBMzAPLEDIA8MQMgT8wAyBMzAPLEDIA
 8MQMgT8wAyBMzAPLEDIA8MQMgT8wAyBMzAPLEDIC8Z2vhmdlaesXNfs85K+veKM7sm/zdir+F
 G1v/OVvczADIEzMA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIEzMA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIEzMA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIE
 zMA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIEzMA8sQMgLw552zPwC80Myvrbn3PN/st/gbt9+tu9vtp695wMwMgT8
 wAyBMzAPLEDIA8MQMgT8wAyBMzAPLEDIA8MQMgT8wAyBMzAPLEDIA8MQMgT8wAyBMzAPLEDIA
 8MQMgT8wAyBMzAPKerYVnZmtpvuics/Lsp30bW/u9eUdbbs5qa7/FmYvczADIEzMA8sQMgDwx
 AyBPzADIEzMA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIEzMA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIEzMA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIEzMA8
 sQMgLxne4BXnHO2R8iYGev+cDff881+P+2stpj5PdzMAMgTMwDyxAyAPDEDIE/MAMgTMwDyxA
 yAPDEDIE/MAMgTMwDyxAyAPDEDIE/MAMgTMwDyxAyAPDEDIE/MAMgTMwDyxAyAvGd7gHebme0
 Rvu2csz3Ct93MfPOOimdV/CZv2O/XbX3PxZndzADIEzMA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIEzMA8sQMgDwx
 AyBPzADIEzMA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIEzMA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIEzMA8sQMgLxnewD4q3POy8/Oz
 Mq6vMfWt7Fla+bib8HNDIA8MQMgT8wAyBMzAPLEDIA8MQMgT8wAyBMzAPLEDIA8MQMgT8wAyB
 MzAPLEDIA8MQMgT8wAyBMzAPLEDIA8MQMgT8wAyHu2B+B3mpntEb7tZuZzzsqzN4rv6MbNOW9
 9GzduZi7u180MgDwxAyBPzADIEzMA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIEzMA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIEzMA8sQM
 gDwxAyBPzADIEzMA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIe7YHeLdzzvYI/EHF9zszLz9b3O+Wm3Mu+rRvw80Mg
 DwxAyBPzADIEzMA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIEzMA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIEzMA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIEz
 MA8sQMgDwxAyBPzADIe7YHeMXMbI/AH3TOWVn3076rm3O+OaviujfM/B5uZgDkiRkAeWIGQJ6
 YAZAnZgDkiRkAeWIGQJ6YAZAnZgDkiRkAeWIGQJ6YAZAnZgDkiRkAeWIGQJ6YAZAnZgDkiRkA
 eWIGQN6cc7ZnAIArbmYA5IkZAHliBkCemAGQJ2YA5IkZAHliBkCemAGQJ2YA5IkZAHliBkCem
 AGQJ2YA5IkZAHliBkCemAGQJ2YA5IkZAHliBkCemAGQJ2YA5IkZAHliBkCemAGQJ2YA5IkZAH
 liBkCemAGQJ2YA5IkZAHliBkCemAGQJ2YA5IkZAHliBkCemAGQJ2YA5IkZAHliBkDe/wB5w4S
 q9G4M2AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
ATTENDEE;CN=Wayne Lee;PARTSTAT=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:song.John@
 company.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:Hello\,\n\nWe hope you enjoy your visit
DTEND:20190723T183343
DTSTAMP:20190723T153343Z
DTSTART:20190723T173343
GEO:52.051681;-4.283453
LOCATION:FranceORGANIZER;CN=Wayne Lee:mailto:wayne@digital-forge.co.uk
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Interview
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
UID:b9fb0c3e-728c-4121-912e-9412885ebbb4
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
SUMMARY:Alert 1 hour before
TRIGGER:-PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

And then trying to send with the following code:

```
       var ical = new TextPart("calendar")
        {
            ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Default,
            ContentDisposition = new ContentDisposition (ContentDisposition.Inline),
            Text = calendar
        };

        ical.ContentType.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
        message.Body = ical;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

The calendar invite comes through fine for me to accept/decline etc but via email, the attachment does not show.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a sample meeting request that I sent to myself from Outlook, Outlook does not add a `Content-Disposition` to the `text/calendar` part.

It also base64 encodes it.

Try this:

```
var ical = new TextPart("calendar")
{
    ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64,
    Text = calendar
};

ical.ContentType.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
```

I also noticed that Outlook tends to construct a MIME message with the following structure (which may or may not be needed):

```
multipart/alternative
    text/plain
    text/html
    text/calendar
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Already had that before but get the same behaviour. Haven't tried looking at setting the other parameters though yet!